# GSM layer 3 messages - System Information Type 2

Tags: gsm

I have 2 questions regarding the GSM standard, specifically about GSM layer 3 messages:

1. How often the network sends "System Information Type 2" to the cellular phone ?
2. Does "System Information Type 2ter" is replacing the "System Information Type 2"? In other words, if the network is enables the "SI 2ter" does "SI 2" will keep trasmitted to the phone or only "SI 2ter" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point for GSM standard. [3GPP Numbering](http://www.3gpp.org/specifications/specification-numbering)

Answer to question 1:

Wiki [Um interface (BTS-MS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Um_interface) i.e. Radio station <-> Mobile
The best way to know, is to listen to all SI :)
The SI 2 is brodcasted in BCCH at operator specific interval, or when MS do an handover or otherwise call for BSC attention. See [04.08 Layer 3 specification](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/0408.htm) for deeper understanding of System Information Message (chapter 3.2.2 and 9.1.32-35), and also [05.02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Um_interface)

Answer to question 2.

The SI2 ter (bis and quarter) are sent when BSC (network) finds it suitable.

Also [05.02](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/0502.htm) specification chapter 6.3.1.3 can be of value.

Links in 3GPP looks like http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/05_series/05.02/0502-8b0.zip